# Cakephp first installation not get the appropriate page

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

Guys i just installed the Cakephp 3.2 using composer following the steps in the official manual http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/installation.html and i instead to get the first homepage i get a page with this code inside:

```
   <?php
/**
 * CakePHP(tm) : Rapid Development Framework (http://cakephp.org)
 * Copyright (c) Cake Software Foundation, Inc. (http://cakefoundation.org)
 *
 * Licensed under The MIT License
 * For full copyright and license information, please see the LICENSE.txt
 * Redistributions of files must retain the above copyright notice.
 *
 * @copyright     Copyright (c) Cake Software Foundation, Inc. (http://cakefoundation.org)
 * @link          http://cakephp.org CakePHP(tm) Project
 * @since         0.10.0
 * @license       http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php MIT License
 */

require 'webroot' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'index.php';
```

Do you have any ideas what could be wrong ?

Comment: **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121495/php-code-is-not-being-executed-instead-code-shows-on-the-page**

Comment: Try download manually and tell us what appears.

Comment: Give us a print of your browser result, including what URL you are accessing. Tested here, and feels ok.

Comment: Url is http://localhost/testcaket , print screen not needed because i copy and paste above exactly the content of the browser :)

Answer (score 0):

i found the prob, was owner permissions.

```
chown -R www-data:www-data test1cake/
```